# AsyncTask doInBackground method is not calling

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using cognitouserpool codes inside AsynTask class's doInBackground method. But my method is not calling. I have tried by checking it with a Log. It is not working.

### AsyncTask

```
    public class AWSInitiator extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private Context context;
        public AWSInitiator(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            CognitoUserPool.......
        Log.i("ACCESS_TOKEN", "Test");
        AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {
            Log.i("ACCESS_TOKEN", userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken());
            ...
        }
    }
```

### AnotherClass.java

```
public class TokenAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) {
        Log.i("Authenticate", "auth");
    AWSInitiator awsInitiator = new AWSInitiator(AppSetting.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        awsInitiator.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    } else {
         awsInitiator.execute();
    }
return response.request().newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppSetting.getInstance().getSDKDataManager().getAccessToken())
                .build();
    }
}
```

But the Log is not showing. Am I doing anything wrong in my coding. I exactly need the token to pass as the header while doing a POST call to AWS server. But it returns null because doInBackground() is not working. Even the Log in the TokenAuthenticator class is also not woking

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually printing the log inside doInBackground method. You are trying to print it in callback method when token fetch is complete. I'm assuming your callback was never invoked which is actually printing the logs.

```
Log.i("ACCESS_TOKEN", userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken());
```

To verify what I'm saying print add new a Log statement outside and you should see logs getting printed in console. Something like :

```
Log.i("ACCESS_TOKEN", "Test logs");
```

Comment: You're correct. I've checked outside callback method. Even that is also not working

Comment: I have edited my question. Please refer the TokenAuthenticator class in my question

Comment: I think you should split your issue in two parts
1. call execute/executeOnExecutor on your async task and check whether "doInBackground" is getting invoked or not. You could do this by putting breakpoint or putting Logs outside callback method.
2. After you have verified doInBackground method is getting invoked, debug your authenticator class.

Async task is very straight forward and with the code you have provided it should work and "doinBackground" should get invoked. I think there is some problem with your authenticator class.

Comment: I have checked "doinBackground" is not getting invoked